# How Micro-services does authorization in asynchronous communication?

Tags: .net, azure, asp.net-core, jwt, microservices

I was implementing the authentication and authorization of a group of micro-services developed in ASP.NET core and a UI. The interaction/communication is between:

1. UI <--> Micro-services through API gateway(OCELOT), Authorization is being done through JWT.(No issues in this case)
2. Micro-services <--> Micro-services, is asynchronous and done through Azure Service Bus.

Wondering how we can implement Authorization in the CASE-2,  Micro-services <--> Micro-services using JWT.
Here do not wanted to implement through Certificate based. Although
we have made some protection through Private network, white-listing
but considering defense of depth, can we also implement
Authorization during JWT considering asynchronous communication
between Micro-services? It it a good practice to do so? and How to
Implement JWT in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the API Gateway, modify the request being sent downstream to backend micro-service.
In this request, inject the `Bearer` token, i.e. the JWT. Now each micro-service has access to the JWT sent by the user.
When MS-1 talks to MS-2, include this token in the HTTP headers and then let MS-2 make the decision based on the roles/claims in JWT.
In case of `ServiceBus`, create the message to include the JWT so that the consumer has access to that token after deserializing.

Comment: If I understood, MS1 is not aware of MS2. It only put a message on a queue, which will be consumed by MS2

Comment: @user3169330 : what in case if MS1 calling MS2, without any user input.

Comment: But would MS1 ever call MS2 `WITHOUT` an API Gateway request from the user with JwT? no, right? so then MS1 will always have the JwT presented by the user and injected into the HTTP header by the API Gateway. Then MS1 shall extract that JwT and then put it in the Service Bus message. HTH